# How to check if an old answer is up to date?

Tags: discussion, old-questions

I broadly have the same question as the answered question
[Angular 2 - large scale application forms' handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806779/angular-2-large-scale-application-forms-handling)

Whilst the answer is not too old (3.5 years) by Stack Overflow standards, I wanted to check with the community if the answer is up to date for **Angular 6+** or if there are any more modern methods.

The user who posted the accepted answer looks like they have long stopped posting, so a comment asking seems inappropriate and there doesn't seem to be the option to add a bounty.

Is there a way to reasonable way revive the question other than asking a new question (including a link to this post plus any research)?

Comment: Doing your own research and testing the answer on an updated code base?

Comment: @yivi's right; simplest way to know is to just try it yourself and find out.

Comment: While the user may have stopped posting long ago, their profile says they were last seen only two months ago. There is a good chance if you leave a comment under one of their posts that they will see it before too long in their notifications box.

Comment: _and there doesn't seem to be the option to add a bounty_ The "start bounty" link is right there.

Comment: yes, I fully intend to test the accepted answer. I want to add to the community - not just take away. There seems to be 5 stars and only 2 upvotes (including me) so it makes me wonder if people are hoping for a better solution. Oops overlooked the bounty, my bad.

Comment: Hmm, that's maybe "old" for Google, not for SO.  You do pay a non-zero price for taking a dependency on their freeware, it is only truly free if your time is free.  That user's time is not free either, testing the proposed solution is required.

Comment: I don't understand the negs - should I not ask if I'm unsure of correct protocol and couldn't find the answer on meta?

Comment: I think people are wondering why you're asking, instead of just trying it.  It would probably be faster to do so than asking your own question, or asking the answerer to confirm it still works.  SO is supposed to be a repository to withstand the test of time, so it's reasonable to assume it should, unless there's a comment or other feedback to indicate it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

> How to check if an old answer is up to date?

You already have an answer, you presumably have a more "up to date" installation set-up... Just try it out yourself?

What stops you from *checking the answer* on your own to see if it is up to date?

> The user who posted the accepted answer looks like they have long stopped posting, so a comment asking seems inappropriate

A comment is not necessarily inappropriate, but personally I do not think it's a great idea. The answer is already posted. You want to know if this works with different requirements than when asked/answered, just test it yourself.

If you find it doesn't do additional research and maybe you can post either a new question or better yet a new answer to document how it is done under a more modern installation.

> and there doesn't seem to be the option to add a bounty.

The "start bounty" is right there. It seems you just missed it.

Comment: Meh. Not so sure of the question being all that great. But I'll let Angular experts cast their judgement. The _"Is there a better way to achieve what we’re trying to do?"_ at the end doesn't smell all that great.